# No matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>::insert(std::pair<int, int>, int)’ vis.insert(make_pair(1,2),3);

Tags: c++, stl

I wrote a simple code as below,which use pair as key in map,

```
map<pair<int, int>, int> vis;
int main(
                )
{
        vis.insert(make_pair(1,2),3);
        return 0;
}
```

And i am getting error on line **vis.insert(make_pair(1,2),3)** , as " **no matching function for call to ‘std::map, int>::insert(std::pair, int)’**
  vis.insert(make_pair(1,2),3);" .Anybody know why am i getting this error?

Comment: That isn't how you insert a k/v pair in to your map. `std::make_pair(std::make_pair(1,2),3))` should be the **single** argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map's key is a pair, and the value is an integer. The problem is that `insert()` gets one parameter, which is a pair of key and value. You have two options:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> vis;
int main(
                )
{
    // option one (c++11 and later)
    vis.emplace(std::make_pair(1,2),3);

    // option two - pack key and value into a single pair.
    vis.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(1,2),3));

    // option three - use braces (c++11 and later)
    vis.insert({{1,2},3});

    return 0;
}
```